# Custom Radio Button React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, radio-button

Hey there so i'm new to react native and javascript and currently i'm learning to make a custom radio button with images it looks like this [my custom radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laQYU.png) in this page user is going to pick one button from the list, and i want to make it when the page first render it will show one pressed button and user is only allowed to pick one button. Can anyone tell me how to figure this out? Thanks in advance

here are my codes

RadioButton.js

```js
export default class RadioButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selected: this.props.currentSelection === this.props.value,
        }
    }

    button() {
        var imgSource = this.state.selected? this.props.normalImg : this.props.selectedImg;
        return (
          <Image
            source={ imgSource }
          />
        );
      }

      render() {
        let activeButton = this.props.activeStyle ? this.props.activeStyle : styles.activeButton;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, this.props.containerStyle, this.state.selected || this.props.normalImg ? activeButton : inactiveButton]}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ selected: !this.state.selected });
                    
                }}>
                    {
                       this.button()
                    }
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

ActivityLog.js

```js
class ActivityLog extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.dialogText}>{`Log my activity at ${time} as...`}</Text>
                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <RadioButton selectedImg={img.activity.breakA} normalImg={img.activity.break} containerStyle={{marginHorizontal: normalize(10)}}/>
                            <RadioButton selectedImg={img.activity.meetingA} normalImg={img.activity.meeting} containerStyle={{marginHorizontal: normalize(10)}}/>
                        </View>

                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <RadioButton selectedImg={img.activity.otwA} normalImg={img.activity.otw} containerStyle={{marginHorizontal: normalize(10)}}/>
                            <RadioButton selectedImg={img.activity.officeA} normalImg={img.activity.office} containerStyle={{marginHorizontal: normalize(10)}}/>
                        </View>
      );
    }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the activeStatus to ActivityLog so as to track which button is selected,right now you are maintaing a state for every button as a local state.So it is difficult to know other components to know about the button's active status.

Here is a generic implementation for rough idea.

```
const Child=(props)=>{
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.handlePress}>
        <Text style={[baseStyle,active && activeStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
class Parent extends React.Component{
 state={
  selectedChild:''
 }
 changeSelection=(sometitle)=>{
  this.setState({
      selectedChild:sometitle
  })
 }
 render(){
     return(
         <View>
             <Child handlePress={()=>this.changeSelection('1')} active={this.state.selectedChild==='1'}/>
             <Child handlePress={()=>this.changeSelection('2')} active={this.state.selectedChild==='2'}/>
             <Child handlePress={()=>this.changeSelection('3')} active={this.state.selectedChild==='3'}/>
             <Child handlePress={()=>this.changeSelection('4')} active={this.state.selectedChild==='4'}/>
         </View>
     )
 }
}
```

Expo demo [Link](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/radio-button)